# Echo en PHP me duplica valores

Tags: php

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema tengo en una variable de tipo string una url almacenada, y al hacer echo de la misma me duplica parte de la misma.

```php
$postURL = '"' . "\/es\/es\/" . $postName . "\/" . '"';
```

Me da como resultado esto:

```
"\/es\/es\/es\/prueba\/"
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?, he probado con str_replace, preg_replace, split_replace, echo, print, print_r,var_dump, var_export...

Por qué añade un "/es/" más?

Añadir que la variable $postURL la imprimo al log y se ve perfectamente, el problema es cuando hago el echo.

Gracias.

Comment: Echo no duplica. Probablemente `$postName` lleve ese texto adicional

Comment: @JDev La variable no lo trae. Eso está comprobado. Si yo depuro la variable $postURL en la consola está perfecto, hago el echo una línea después y sale mal.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no duplica nada. https://ideone.com/7J3RZ6

Comment: sería bueno saber que valores tiene $postname o como lo llenas

Comment: Necesitas compartir un poco más de tu código y problemática para que podamos entender que sucede con `$postName` antes de llegar a esa línea. De ser posible revisa esa variable desde que la declaras hasta que llega a ese punto.

Comment: @Solrac La variable $postName le llega "prueba-articulo"
Yo también lo pruebo fuera y funciona pero ahí no. Es una locura, no entiendo que pasa.

Comment: El tema es. ¿Cómo es posible que en una línea escriba en el log el resultado y este perfecto, y que la siguiente línea de código haga un echo y este el valor mal?

Comment: Algo mas debes de tener en el código o en la configuración porque si no es imposible.

Comment: @JDev estoy con vosotros creo que $postName lleva implicito ese texto

Comment: @JDev Si, lo sé es imposible. Pero me ocurre y la variable llega lo que os digo, tanto haciendo echo de la misma, como imprimiéndola en consola.

Comment: @KeTeMeTo La variable $postName llega sin nada más que lo que tiene que llevar.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner todo el código a ver si vemos algo mas?

Comment: @JDev +1 estoy de acuerdo así no se que puede pasar